# Which file descriptors (/dev/fd/##) are used in process substitution?

Tags: bash, application-development, filesystem

I have a program which takes 2 inputs:

```
my_program --input1 {videoFile1} --input2 {videoFile2}
```

I want to redirect my inputs through process substitution (because my inputs are large video files, which I want to transcode on-the-fly).  Through experiment, I'm using the following, which is functionally fine:

```
my_program --input1 /dev/fd/63 --input2 /dev/fd/62 <( {video transcoding command 1} ) <( {video transcoding command 2} )
```

My question is : why are the file descriptor numbers 63 and 62?  Are they always guaranteed to take those values, or is this system-dependent?

Apologies if this is well-documented, but I can't find it in my searches so far.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question - but, in bash, shouldn't `my_program --input1 <( {video transcoding command 1} ) --input2 <( {video transcoding command 2} )` be equivalent, without the need to specify the pipe file descriptor explicitly?

Comment: Aha, I was not aware of that syntax.  Yes, that's exactly what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Videoprocessing is wellknown for seeking into the file. That means that you cannot use a stream as input. And if you are using output from another program, then it is a stream - no matter whether you use pipes or fds.

But maybe you are in luck that *your* program can use pipes. In that case this should be fine:

```
my_program --input1 <( {video transcoding command 1} ) --input2 <( {video transcoding command 2} )
```

The <() may look as if it is giving you something on stdin just like < does. But it does not. Instead it is substituted with a link to the pipe:

```
$ echo <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true) <(true)
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/61 /dev/fd/60 /dev/fd/59 /dev/fd/58 /dev/fd/57 /dev/fd/56 /dev/fd/55 /dev/fd/54 /dev/fd/53 /dev/fd/52 /dev/fd/51 /dev/fd/50 /dev/fd/49 /dev/fd/48 /dev/fd/47 /dev/fd/46 /dev/fd/45 /dev/fd/44 /dev/fd/43 /dev/fd/42 /dev/fd/41 /dev/fd/40 /dev/fd/39 /dev/fd/38 /dev/fd/37 /dev/fd/36 /dev/fd/35 /dev/fd/34 /dev/fd/33 /dev/fd/32 /dev/fd/31 /dev/fd/30 /dev/fd/29 /dev/fd/28 /dev/fd/27 /dev/fd/26 /dev/fd/25 /dev/fd/24 /dev/fd/23 /dev/fd/22 /dev/fd/21 /dev/fd/20 /dev/fd/19 /dev/fd/18 /dev/fd/17 /dev/fd/16 /dev/fd/15 /dev/fd/14 /dev/fd/13 /dev/fd/12 /dev/fd/11 /dev/fd/10 /dev/fd/9 /dev/fd/8 /dev/fd/7 /dev/fd/6 /dev/fd/5 /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/64 /dev/fd/65 /dev/fd/66 /dev/fd/67
$ ls -l <(true)
lr-x------ 1 tange tange 64 Nov 12 07:59 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[1200523]
```

So you may be in situations where this makes sense:

```
$ cmd 2> >(cmd2) | cmd3
```

Comment: It is indeed the case that my program can use pipes (and has been written specifically with that case in mind).  I wasn't aware of the syntax to redirect a command into each input (your first code block above), which is exactly what I need.  Thanks!